# Clarification about Annotations in Java

Tags: java, servlets, annotations

I am looking for some clarification regarding Annotations in Java. Following page from Oracle https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/  says "Annotations have no direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate.",  but I execute a piece of code like this

```
@WebServlet("/ServletLifeCycleExample")            
public class ServletLifeCycleExample extends HttpServlet {      
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;       
public ServletLifeCycleExample() {       
    super();          
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub        
}
```

The line `@WebServlet("/ServletLifeCycleExample")` is very critical to the successful working of the code , even though its an annotation. Without the line the code just collapses (the servlet ServletLifeCycleExample does not get loaded).

How to explain this?

Comment: Have you read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html)?

Comment: The javadoc has this relevant comment "This annotation is processed by the container at deployment time, and the corresponding servlet made available at the specified URL patterns.", but even this comment is in contradiction to the more general comment that "Annotations have no direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate."  ...Question is - Can Annotations have direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate.?

Comment: No. They are just metadata. But a container can use that metadata.

Answer (score 0):

"More generally, annotations never change the semantics of the annotated code, but
enable it for special treatment by tools" ~Effective Java 2nd Edition

In this case the the WebServlet annotation has an *indirect* effect, which happens to be very important.

Answer (score -1):

Annotation marks class and add meta data to it. When some engine (spring/app server/etc) load class with annotation it can read data from annotation (or just check if annotation present) and change it behaviour like open transaction before pass call to your class